# How can I allow the"+" signal

Tags: regex

I have this regex that doesn't allow the "+" signal, I need to use this one and allow the plus.

```
/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,28}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$/
```

I want to allow the "+" signal, how can I allow in this regex?
This is my confirmation:

```
var re = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,28}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$/;
return re.test(email);
```

Comment: just add `+` symbol at the start of all character class.

Comment: can you show me how please, im new on this

Comment: Hi , but where do you want to allow that  ' **+** ' please explain

Comment: I woudn’t re-invent the wheel. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment add `+` inside all the character classes.

```
^[+\w-]+(\.[+\w-]+)*@([+a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[+a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,28}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pH3wX8/1)